# Difference between the execution of a+=2 and a=a+2?

Tags: callbyname, call-by-value

```
void increment(int a)
{
    a+=2
}

void assign(int a)
{
    a=a+2
}
```

In which of the parameter passing technique a call to increment(b) will have a different effect
 from a call to assign(b)

1) call by value
 2) call by value result
 3) call by reference
 4) call by name

Comment: What is the language / tool you are using?

Comment: I am not using anything it is just a question i came across to and was curious to find if the execution of expressions a+=2 and a=a+2 makes the real difference ?

Comment: and if it makes then after using which type of call it would make the difference ?

Comment: neither of these function do anything (assuming c / c++ type languages)

Answer (score 0):

The first is one operation ie store value a+2 in a (+=)
The second is two operations ie calculate value a+2 (+) and assign to a (=)

It is very dependent on language though how these are implemented.

Comment: okay, can you say In which of the following parameter passing technique a call to increment(b) will have a different effect from a call to assign(b) and why ?

1) call by value 2) call by value result 3) call by reference 4) call by name

Comment: The final result will be the same regardless. Just one of them (+=) in some cases could be more optimal

Answer (score 0):

In most cases (assuming x += y is equivalent to x = x + y), no difference. Also, in most languages both functions will not affect the value passed to it, so these are doing nothing.